# Would an eyemask obscure a persons identity?

Tags: psychology, physiology

Often in movies and comics characters wear a simple mask around the eyes, which seems successful at hiding their identities.

Examples would be Zorro, Green Lantern, Robin

[image] [Image source](http://www.examiner.com/green-celebrity-in-national/green-celebrity-news-first-photos-leak-of-green-lantern-art-poster-featuring-ryan-reynolds)

Is there any evidence to suggest that a face being obscured in this way would prevent most people from recognizing the face?

Bonus question: What would be the minimum extent to which you could obscure a face and prevent positive identification?

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe interesting: [Obscuring part of the face to avoid *computer-based* face recognition algorithms.](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/04/22/face_detection_hacking/)

Comment: I think a lot would depend on the face. If the mask e.g. hides a prominent scar, it would be more likely to hide one's identity than if one's face were pretty similar to those of the average person in the population.

Comment: Related: [Clark Kenting](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ClarkKenting)

Comment: Has this ever been claimed outside of a fantasy movie?

Comment: @djc yes. Venetian carnival masks are a similar real world claim.

Comment: Are the Venetian carnival masks actually are intended to hide the identity?

Comment: @djc yes, that seems to have [been their purpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venetian_masks) - "*The mask would permit the wearer to act more freely in cases where he or she wanted to interact with other members of the society **outside the bounds of identity** and everyday convention.*"

Comment: Most of the masks mentioned in that article are much fuller than the eye-mask mentioned here. Does anyone have an example of a Venetian mask that is like the ones described here?

Comment: Eyemasks are described in that article and were used to hide identity. It doesn't matter that *most* of the masks were fuller masks.

Comment: It's all about glasses. Just ask Clark Kent.
Seriously though, eye masks don't do much to obscure the main features of a face. Most facial recognition comes from proportions of the face relative to one another. Placement of eyes versus nose and ear lobes, that sort of thing, are important.
I haven't read the research on this so can't answer fully.

Comment: @DJClayworth http://www.google.com/search?q=maschera+veneziana

Comment: I'm unconvinced. @SonnyOrdell the statement in Wikipedia is unreferenced (and we all know how reliable such statements are) and the article also states that the reasons for wearing are unknown, and describes only masks that are fuller than the eyemask.

Comment: @Sklivvz your Google search only proves that *some people* call eyemasks "maschera venezia" and does not demonstrate that they were used for actual disguise.

Comment: @DJClayworth Fair enough. I still don't see a problem with the question, given how widespread eye masks are portrayed as being able to hide an identity. It's falsifiable and the claim is notable. I don't see an issue.

Comment: I originally asked if there was a claim of this outside fantasy fiction?

Comment: I doubt it, since I can generally recognize people I know without even seeing their faces.  (And have a hard time recognizing them from pictures that show only the face.)  Re the Venetian masks, I suggest two factors might have been at work.  First, social convention: if someone is wearing a mask, you pretend not to recognize them even when you do.  Second, the costumes as shown in the Wikipedia link above obscure the whole body, making recognition difficult even if the face is visible.